# Manipulation of div elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain to me or figure it out. I dont know where I made a mistake here. I have javascript and html code where I get input from user for a flight. I want to make a counter to count all flights `function counter()` but it gives me the value of name. And another problem is I want when I click on the Accept button to make the background of the div element green `function changeColor()`.

```js
    function addRow(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var plainNum = document.getElementById("plainNum");
        var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
        var radius = document.getElementById("radius");
        var altitude = document.getElementById("altitude");
        var type = document.getElementById("type");
        if(!name.value || !plainNum.value || !coordinates.value || !radius.value || !altitude.value || !type.value){
            alert("Enter all values");
            return;
        }
        
        
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        var divForOutput = document.createElement("DIV");
        var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var btn2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t1 = document.createTextNode("Accept");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("Reject");
        btn1.appendChild(t1);
        btn2.appendChild(t2);
        divForOutput.innerHTML += name.value +", " + plainNum.value +"<br>" + "Radius: " + radius.value +", "+"Altitude: "+altitude.value+"<br>"+type.value+"<br>";
        divForOutput.appendChild(btn1);
        divForOutput.appendChild(btn2);
        divForOutput.setAttribute('class','printing');
        output.appendChild(divForOutput);
        btn1.setAttribute('onclick','changeColor(this);');
        btn2.setAttribute('onclick','disableButtons()');
        // name.value = "";
        // plainNum.value = "";
        // coordinates.value = "";
        // radius.value = "";
        // altitude.value = "";
        counter();
    }
    function disableButtons(){}
    function changeColor(){
        var parentofChild = document.getElementById("output");
        output.div.background = green;
    }
    function counter(){;
        var sum = document.getElementsByClassName("printing");
        var counter = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i <sum.length;i++){
            counter+=parseInt(sum[i].innerHTML);
        }
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = counter;
    }
```

```html
    <h1>Register flight</h1>
<form>
    
    <div>
        <label>Name and surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Number plate</label>
        <input type="text" id="plainNum">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Coordinates</label>
        <input type="text" id="coordinates">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Radius</label>
        <input type="text" id="radius">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Altitude</label>
        <input type="text" id="altitude">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Type</label>
        <select id="type">
            <option value="Comercial">Comercial</option>
            <option value="Buissines">Buissines</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addRow();">
    </div>
</form>
<divи>
    <h3>Registered flights</h3>
    <p>Total:<span id="total">0</span></p>
    
</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: Your `divForOutput` (which are the elements of class `printing`) contains a whole lot of HTML, starting with the name value.  Which integer did you think you were parsing?  And `output.div.background` does nothing, because `output.div` is undefined.  What did you think that was doing?

Comment: And you seem to have syntax errors like function counter(){;

Comment: @JohnMalkowich It's not a syntax error, `;` is the empty statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I've fixed some of the code and made things a bit better.

```js
    function addRow(){
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var plainNum = document.getElementById("plainNum");
        var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
        var radius = document.getElementById("radius");
        var altitude = document.getElementById("altitude");
        var type = document.getElementById("type");
        if(!name.value || !plainNum.value || !coordinates.value || !radius.value || !altitude.value || !type.value){
            alert("Enter all values");
            return;
        }
        
        
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        var divForOutput = document.createElement("DIV");
        //var btn1 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        //var btn2 = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        //var t1 = document.createTextNode("Accept");
        //var t2 = document.createTextNode("Reject");
        //btn1.appendChild(t1);
        //btn2.appendChild(t2);
        divForOutput.innerHTML = `
${name.value}<br>
Radius: ${radius.value}<br>
Altitude: ${altitude.value}<br>
${type.value}<br>
<button onclick="changeColor();">Accept</button>
<button onclick="disableButtons();">Reject</button>
`;
        divForOutput.appendChild(btn1);
        divForOutput.appendChild(btn2);
        divForOutput.setAttribute('class','printing');
        output.appendChild(divForOutput);
        //btn1.setAttribute('onclick','changeColor(this);');
        //btn2.setAttribute('onclick','disableButtons()');
        // name.value = "";
        // plainNum.value = "";
        // coordinates.value = "";
        // radius.value = "";
        // altitude.value = "";
        counter();
    }
    function disableButtons(){}
    function changeColor(){
        const output = document.getElementById("output");
        output.style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
    }
    function counter(){;
        const sum = document.getElementsByClassName("printing");
        const counter = sum.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
        return document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = counter;
    }
```

There is an explanation for the background color [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70160051/14544118)

As for the counter; what I did was count the div elements inside of the `output` div. That will give you the amount of flights a user has.

Answer (score 0):

Your color setting had several problems.  You don't use `output.div.background` to set the color, and you were using the undefined variable `green` instead of the string `"green"`.  This works:

```
    function changeColor(){
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        output.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
```

I don't know what you are trying to count with your `counter` function, so I can't fix that.